# Delete a sequence of redundant letters in Python

Tags: python

I want to be able to delete a sequence of repeated letters in a word in python .Let's say the word is "helllllllo" , I want to be able to delete the repeated letter which appears more than twice. The only solution I found was a nested loop, but in terms of performance, especially when the dataset is large, it can get quite heavy. Are there any alternatives for this problem ?

Comment: Actually the problem is it is very slow to remove some letters from a string as you have to rewrite the complete string even then it is very difficult to make a logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
s = 'helllllloolloolloollolo'
t = ''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(s) if i < 2 or not(c == s[i-1] and c == s[i-2]))
print(t)
```

Output:

```
helloolloolloollolo
```

The argument to `join` is a comprehension that filters out characters in s that are the same as the two preceding characters. Then `join` turns the resulting sequence into a string.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are two sets of repeated characters separated by a single character ie ```'hellolloll'``` result: ```'hellolol'```

Comment: @Nin17 please see updated answer (first draft had a bug ...)

Comment: Yep, you've fixed that. I don't think you need the ```if  i < 2``` and it can just be ```''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(s) if not (c == s[i-1] and c == s[i-2]))``` and you can remove the ```not``` and make it ```''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(s) if (c != s[i-1] or c != s[i-2]))```

Comment: I think removing that would result in throwing an exception for strings with only less than two characters, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @SashSinha yeah fair point, didn't think about that

Comment: Just for fun, could also do this: `t = ''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(s) if i < 2 or s[i-2:i+1] != c*3)
`